# ORA-00905: missing keyword during merge in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Good Afternoon,

this statement works...

```
merge into temp using(select * from emp where deptno=10) s on (temp.empno=s.empno)
when matched then update set temp.sal=s.sal*0.1 where sal > 300
when not matched then insert (temp.ename,temp.sal )values (s.ename,s.sal*0.1) where (s.sal<300);
```

but when i am trying to use the following merge command. i am ending up with the missing keyword error

```
sql> **merge into temp using (select * from emp where deptno=10) on (1=1);**
```

i created temp with the structure similar to the emp table

Can someone please help me out. I want to actually copy the content for my emp table into temp table `where deptno=10` using merge command

Comment: either UPDATE or INSERT is mandatory in MERGE clause

Comment: But this is the syntax which i found in oracle docs                                    MERGE [ hint ]
   INTO [ schema. ] { table | view } [ t_alias ]
   USING [ schema. ] { table | view | subquery }
     [ t_alias ]
   ON ( condition )
   [ merge_update_clause ]
   [ merge_insert_clause ]
   [ error_logging_clause ] ; where update or insert is option.....i am not sure please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: There is a small note in the Oracle reference: "Note: You must specify at least one of the clauses merge_update_clause or merge_insert_clause."

Comment: What do you what to do ON (1=1)? According to MERGE syntax it's always true so you want to update. Update what?

Comment: i want to update the temp table with all the rows that have deptno as 10 in emp table

Answer (score 2):

```
merge into temp target 
using (select * from emp where deptno=10) source on (target.empid = source.empid)
when matched then update set target.sal=source.sal*0.1;
```

You cannot use ON (1=1) with MERGE because MERGE is deterministic.

> MERGE is a deterministic statement. You cannot update the same row of
>   the target table multiple times in the same MERGE statement.

However, it's not true for insert. You may use ON (1=0) for example to insert whatever you want.